# Android - HttpGet with parameters

Tags: android, android-asynctask, slim

I'm doing a REST API in Android with my `GET` method using Slim framework. I didn't have any problem about retrieving all the values of a table, for example, `cars`.

The problem comes when I try to access to the `name` of a `Car` by it's `id`. I have the method on Slim framework created and it works perfectly:

**GET METHOD**

```
$app->get("/cars/:idCar",function($idCar) use($app)
{
    try{
        $connection = getConnection();
        $dbh = $connection->prepare("SELECT name FROM cars WHERE idCar = ?");
        $dbh->bindParam(1,$idCar);
        $dbh->execute();
        $car = $dbh->fetchObject();
        $connection = null;

        header("HTTP/1.1 200");
        header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");

        echo json_encode($car,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

And if I put the url on my browser:

```
http://IP of my computer/project/cars/1
```

it returns to me:

```
{"name":"Car1"}
```

So in the `GET` method there isn't any problem.

---

The problem it's when I try to execute `HttpGet`, because I get stuck of what I have to do. What I have right now:

**HttpGet method inside the AsyncTask**

```
class FindCar extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

   protected void onPreExecute(){
   }

   protected Void doInBackground(Integer... idCar) {

      String url = "http://IP of my computer/project/cars/" + idCar[0].intValue();

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);

      method.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

      try {
          HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(method);

          String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

          JSONArray respJSON = new JSONArray(respStr);

          for (int i = 0; i < respJSON.length(); i++) {

               JSONObject obj = respJSON.getJSONObject(i);

               String name = obj.getString("name");
          }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

          return null;
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(){
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(){
   }
}
```

And it gives to me some **questions**:

- Should I create a `JSONArray` just for one attribute?
- What is the best practice to get the name in my AsyncTask?
- After getting the `name` by the `id` of my `Car` that I pass to my `AsyncTask`, how can I return it out of the `AsyncTask`?
- Should I create a `NameValuePair` to set the value of my `id`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the JSONArray (since there is no square brackets in the responce)! Please try instead of

```
      JSONArray respJSON = new JSONArray(respStr);
      for (int i = 0; i < respJSON.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject obj = respJSON.getJSONObject(i);
           String name = obj.getString("name");
      }
```

the following:

```
      JSONObject respJSON = new JSONObject(respStr);
      String name = respJSON.getString("name");
```

As for returning the result - return it from doInBackground to onPostExecute method then store it somewhere (you can show it on the screen since onPostExecute runs on UI thread). To return value from doInBackground change last type param of `AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>` from `Void` to other type.

Best practice is do not use AsyncTask and do not parse JSON manually (when it is possible) :) Retrofit would be a good choice

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what I wanted! ;)

Answer (score 1):

**i use something like this:**

```
public function getCarsById($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM cars WHERE idCar = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $car= $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $car;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Regarding the java class, i use [Retrofi](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) that is incredible fast and can be used **Synchronous** and **Asynchronous**.

Comment: As I said in the question, with the GET method I didn't have any problem, just in the Android HttpGet. Anyway, thank you for the help provided!